# Sandbox Refresh/Create and Robots.txt

Tags: force.com-sites, sandbox, sandbox-refresh

Production has a robots.txt file setup and associate to the public facing site. Now if a sandbox is refreshed or created is the live robots.txt associated to the site in the sandbox or is the default Salesforce robots.txt file used?

Unfortunately I am unable to test this myself and I have not been able to find any documentation answering this.

I am using force.com sites.

**Update from Salesforce Support:**

> As per your query " if our Production environment force.com site has a
>   robots.txt file setup and then a sandbox is refreshed or created does
>   the sandbox use the production version of the robots.txt file or the
>   default Salesforce robots.txt" on consultation with the project
>   manager and the senior developer support the answer to this would be
>   Yes the robot.txt file gets updated automatically to the one that is
>   present in the production upon sandbox refresh/create.
>
> Currently we do not have a documentation to support this but I believe
>   that the default robot.txt will get updated to the one in production

I'll add it as an answer once I can confirm that's true.

Comment: is it site.com or sites ?

Comment: force.com sites (added to question).

Comment: I would assume it does but in case it does not there will be some way to do this via metadata API or manually

Comment: I actually don't want it to! I can think of a few ways to handle it...I'm just not sure if I need to because I can't test it. I'm kinda hoping someone has refreshed or created a sandbox recently and can check for me :)